# How to costumize marker maps on react-native ? (RN-vs : 0.59)

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native

I have tried to costumizing maps marker on react-native.. but i didnt get the change marker on my android.. the app always force close after i write code like bellow.. Please help.. thanks..

```js
render() {

        return (
            // <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
                ref={ref => myMap = ref}
                style={{
                    flex: 1
                }}
                region={this.props.region}
                showsUserLocation={true}
            >
                {
                    this.state.data.map((value, key) => {
                        return (

                            <MapView.Marker
                                coordinate={{ latitude: value.region.latitude, longitude: value.region.longitude }}
                                key={key}
                                title={value.title}
                                description={value.desc}
                                image={require('../../../Assets/Ruko.png')}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    myMap.fitToCoordinates([{ latitude: value.region.latitude, longitude: value.region.longitude }], {
                                        edgePadding: { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 },
                                        animated: true
                                    });
                                    this.clickDetail(value.id);
                                }}>

                            </MapView.Marker>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </MapView>
            // </View>
        );
```

Comment: What do you want to change for Marker?

Comment: I want modified marker map with image .png ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add images to the marker prop.

```js
                          <MapView.Marker
                                coordinate={{ latitude: value.region.latitude, longitude: value.region.longitude }}
                                key={key}
                                title={value.title}
                                description={value.desc}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    myMap.fitToCoordinates([{ latitude: value.region.latitude, longitude: value.region.longitude }], {
                                        edgePadding: { top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10 },
                                        animated: true
                                    });
                                    this.clickDetail(value.id);
                                }}>
                            <Image source={require('../../../Assets/Ruko.png')} 
                                     style={{height: 35, width:35 }} />
                            </MapView.Marker>
```